# Getting rid from last four empty lines in a string

Tags: php, string, blank-line

I have an SQL file on Unix that I'm getting with PHP, cutting it from start and from the end and returning it into a `textarea` with AJAX. The file is:

```
Set LINESIZE 1000
set timing on
set FEEDBACK off
SET PAGESIZE 50000
set COLSEP |
set trim on
set RECSEPCHAR ~

select * from tbvalid_value where discrete_code like '%  %' and DISCRETE_CODE != 'U - Unreturned  and billed'
;

exit;
```

after the `exit;` i have another blank line.

What I want to return is only the select statement:

`select * from tbvalid_value where discrete_code like '%  %' and DISCRETE_CODE != 'U - Unreturned  and billed'`

To do this, firstly I'm chopping the first 8 rows with this function:

```
function str_chop_lines($str, $lines = 8) {
    return implode("\n", array_slice(explode("\n", $str), $lines));
};

$sql = str_chop_lines($sqlString);
```

This cuts all the `Set` Statements and the blank 8th line.

Then, I want to get rid from the last part of the string (from the `;` to the `exit;`). For this I'm using this:

```
$finalSql = substr($sql, 0, strpos($sql, ';'));
```

But when I return the string to the client's side `textarea`, I get 4 empty blank lines at the end of it, as seen in this picture (the red lines were added by me to illustrate the 4 blank lines):

[image: Blank Lines]

I've tried to trim these lines with different methods:

`$sqlReturnByAjax = substr($finalSql, 0, strrpos($finalSql, "\n"));`

`$sqlReturnByAjax = str_replace('/n/n', '/n', $finalSql);`

`$sqlReturnByAjax = rtrim($finalSql);`

But non of these worked.
What am I missing ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($finalSql);` output?

Comment: @AmalMurali `string(110) "select * from tbvalid_value where discrete_code like '% %' and DISCRETE_CODE != 'U - Unreturned and billed' "`

Comment: Could them extra lines it be in the textarea?

Comment: The `textarea` is empty before the AJAX returns the string, so why I see 4 new lines on it after ?

Comment: @Alon_A: So what's the issue, exactly? Are you not able to retrieve the required string from the text?

Comment: @AmalMurali issue is that after the text, i get 4 empty lines on the `textarea`, I dont understand where those lines come from ?

Comment: @Alon_A: Is it visible when you view the page source? Can you copy-paste that here? I'm not sure what these characters are.

Comment: AmalMurali the OP has mentioned throughout its from **AJAX**

Comment: Well, as a solution I just trim the string from the client side using Javascript `replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')`. But I still don't get why its being returned with empty rows from the first place...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just simply `trim` the string?

```
echo trim($yourString);
```

It removes newlines, spaces, etc from the beginning and end of the line. [Trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: It still adds 4 empty rows to the `textarea`

Comment: echo your variables throughout, you should use trim() on whatever variable has the whitespace on it.

Comment: I just use Javascript to trim the string after the response is back from the PHP side... Maybe I've missed something but that handles it ;0)

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the file on the server is

```
Set LINESIZE 1000
set timing on
set FEEDBACK off
SET PAGESIZE 50000
set COLSEP |
set trim on
set RECSEPCHAR ~

select * from tbvalid_value where discrete_code like '%  %' and DISCRETE_CODE != 'U - Unreturned  and billed'
;

exit;
```

and you only want the line that starts with the SELECT statement, you could use PHP's `file()` to read file into an array of lines, then find the one you need. E.g.:

```
$sql = '';
$file = file('/path/to/file', FILE_IGNORE_NEWLINES);

foreach($file as $line) {
  if(strpos($line, 'select') === 0) {
    $sql = $line;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: How would this help? You're `break`ing out of the loop on the first iteration itself, so `$sql` would contain the first line of the file, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: The statement can consist more then 1 line, i dont know the number of lines for each statement. I only know I dont want the first 8 rows and the last `;` and `exit;`.